# Run cheerio inside script tags

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, cheerio

Is It possible indent cheerio package inside HTML tag "script"?
Example:

```
   <script>

"cheerios code"

</script>
```

Comment: I don't know why you would need Cheerio's code in a client context. I implore you to look at [this MDN article about DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), especially ```new DOMParser().parseFromString```.

Comment: I'm sorry, the reason is I m confusing myself, I don't know how to scrape a page and put it directly on my html page, I ve been looking for a very long on Web, but all I do is confuse myself. Can you give me an h